# Upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04 from 14.10; computer freezes each time

Tags: 15.04, do-release-upgrade

I have upgraded to Ubuntu yesterday. I used the terminal with the command

> *sudo do-release-upgrade -d*

in order to upgrade ,since update manager does not give me the option to upgrade to Ubuntu 15.04.

It said that there was an error whole updating but I have not recorded it bit I remember it saying something like

**"your computer is in an unusable state".**

Now It can boot fast but after logging in to my profile, I could not run any programs and my computer just freezes. I have not encountered any problems like this with 14.10; my computer was running very smoothly.  What do I do?